# two divs lying horizontally centered in wrapping div

Tags: html, css, center

I'm trying to create an html element like in the image. Buttons are fine, but i can't set two divs below properly. Tried many combinations of floats, position, display etc. but nothing worked. I'm not allowed to change the navbar css.[image]

```css
#navbar5 {
  float: left;
  width: 35%;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar5">
  <button> abc </button>
  <button> def </button>
  <div id="one"> xxxxxxx </div>
  <div id="two"> yyyyyyy </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try it with a Flexbox

Comment: #one and #two - this is buttons? Or inputs?

Comment: #one and #two are just divs with simple text

Comment: You can wrap `one` and `two` with an additional `flex` div

Comment: There are a lot of ways you could do this (flexbox/grid/text-alignment/absolute positioning) It depends a lot on the context. Honestly anything more than text-alignment on some inline-block's seems overkill for this as it's shown in the question. It would be helpful if you could show your attempt/s so far in the question.

Comment: Why can't you just give me the correct answer? I tried a lot of combinations of everything mentioned above, including putting these two divs in wrapping div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
#navbar5 {
  width: auto;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
}

.simple_text {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#two,
#navbar5 button:last-of-type {
  margin: 0 0 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar5">
  <button> abc </button>
  <button> def </button>
  <div class="simple_text">
    <div id="one"> xxxxxxx </div>
    <div id="two"> yyyyyyy </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you,
.simple_text with just these two properties did the job.

Comment: Glad to help you :)